# how to counting True and False of Multiindex in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, count, multi-index

i'm using multiindex in pandas.

Example1 :

```
'info'       '2002'     '2003'     '2004'
'PID' 'Age'  't1' 't2'  't1' 't2'  't1' 't2'
 101   30     Nan  2     2    1     Nan  Nan
 102   28     2    5     1    Nan   10   100
```

I want to know the number of things that are worth either.

[num] and [num] is True

[Nan] and [num] is True

[Nan] and [Nan] is False

Example2 :

```
'info'       
'PID' 'Age' 'count' 
 101   30      2
 102   28      3
```

so i think using a any(), but i did not solve it.

Comment: What is `df.index` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need if `MultiIndex` also in index first check [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) of all values, then check at least one per first level of MultiIndex in columns by [`DataFrameGroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html) and last count `True`s by `sum`:

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[101, 102], [28, 30]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [1, 0]])

df = df.notna().groupby(axis=1, level=0).any().sum(axis=1)
#oldier pandas versions
#df = df.notnull().groupby(axis=1, level=0).any().sum(axis=1)
```

---

If there is no `MultiIndex` in index add [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove `info` level:

```
print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)

s = df.drop('info', level=0, axis=1).notnull().groupby(axis=1, level=0).any().sum(axis=1)
print (s)
0    2
1    3
dtype: int64
```

And if need create column by position use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(2, ('info','count'), s)
print (df)
   info             '2002'      '2003'      '2004'       
  'PID' 'Age' count   't1' 't2'   't1' 't2'   't1'   't2'
0   101    30     2    NaN    2      2  1.0    NaN    NaN
1   102    28     3    2.0    5      1  NaN   10.0  100.0
```

Comment: wow... Your answer was a great help! 

Can I ask more questions?

Comment: @GihunJoo - Sure, come on :)

Comment: I want to represent the counted value as a list. What if you want to represent the frequency of a number as a list?

Comment: @GihunJoo - It is simple, add `s.tolist()`

Comment: But what is `df.index` ?

Comment: What I mean is that I could have a total of 13 counting values ​​from my data, and I would like to express it on a list of 13 frequencies.

Comment: Yes, need convert `s` to list ? `s.tolist()` does not work?

Comment: I have 500,000 data, and counts from 1 to 13. If I do s.tolist(), it will return a list with a length of 500,000. I would like to get the frequency of the resulting list and return a list of length 13.

Comment: Sorry, need `print (s.value_counts())`